# Can connect and write hex files from MPLAB X IPE but can not debug from MPLAB X IDE

Tags: embedded, pic, mplab

Currently using MPLAB X IDE and IPE v6.15 with PIC16F1503 and PICKIT 4 for debugging. I have connected the PICKIT 4 on the ICSP interface with PIC16F1503. I can connect the PICKIT4 and write HEX files to the PIC MCU using MPLAB X IPE but can not debug the program using MPLAB X IDE.

MPLAB X IDE throws error like:

```
Transmission on endpoint 2 failed (err = -109)

A communication error with the debug tool has occurred. The tool will attempt to recover momentarily. A log of the error was created at C:\Users\user\MPLABXProjects\DroneSMD-1000.X\queuelogs\debugtool
Connection Failed.
Transmission on endpoint 2 failed (err = -109)
```

In the error log of `C:\Users\user\MPLABXProjects\DroneSMD-1000.X\queuelogs\debugtool`:

```
236 1700786547343 GEN4_CONNECT_DIAGNOSTICS:MPLABCommTool is null

236 1700786547343 GEN4_TO_CONTROLLER_LOG:GEN4_CONNECT_INT_LOG_PIC16F1503 Pre:GetFirmwareInfo
236 1700786547343 GEN4_TO_CONTROLLER_LOG:GEN4_CONNECT_INT_LOG_PIC16F1503 Payload
236 1700786547343 GEN4_TO_CONTROLLER_LOG:GEN4_CONNECT_INT_LOG_PIC16F1503 null
236 1700786547343 GEN4_TO_CONTROLLER_LOG:GEN4_CONNECT_INT_LOG_PIC16F1503 Payload End
236 1700786547344 XXXX 1700786547344, Thread 236: com.Send returned false 
236 1700786547344 XXXX 1700786547344, Thread 236: execCommand: exception after writeSideChanel null 
236 1700786547344 GEN4_CONNECT_DIAGNOSTICS:Removing plug and play observer com.microchip.mplab.mdbcore.RI4Tool.RI4ToolBase$RI4PlugNPlayObserver@d5365b3
236 1700786547344 GEN4_CONNECT_DIAGNOSTICS:Begin PlugNPlayObservers list dump:
236 1700786547344 GEN4_CONNECT_DIAGNOSTICS:End PlugNPlayObservers list dump:
236 1700786547396 GEN4_CONNECT_DIAGNOSTICS:Calling RIDbgToolCom.Disconnect
236 1700786547396 GEN4_CONNECT_DIAGNOSTICS:Calling MPLABCommTool.Detach to remove tool from plug and play list
236 1700786547396 GEN4_CONNECT_DIAGNOSTICS:Calling RIDbgToolCom.DisconnectFromMPlabComm
236 1700786547396 GEN4_CONNECT_DIAGNOSTICS:Calling MPLABCommTool.Disconnect
256 1700786563815 GEN4_CONNECT_DIAGNOSTICS:MPLABCommTool is NOT null
256 1700786563815 GEN4_CONNECT_DIAGNOSTICS:AttachedToolPID = 9012, AttachedToolVID = 4d8
256 1700786563815 GEN4_CONNECT_DIAGNOSTICS:transport type = USB
256 1700786563815 GEN4_CONNECT_DIAGNOSTICS:AttachedToolPID = 9012, AttachedToolVID = 4d8
256 1700786563821 GEN4_CONNECT_DIAGNOSTICS:Before MPLABCommTool.Connect()
256 1700786563821 GEN4_CONNECT_DIAGNOSTICS:After MPLABCommTool.Connect()
256 1700786563821 GEN4_CONNECT_DIAGNOSTICS:Adding new plug and play observer com.microchip.mplab.mdbcore.RI4Tool.RI4ToolBase$RI4PlugNPlayObserver@390850fb
256 1700786563821 GEN4_CONNECT_DIAGNOSTICS:Begin PlugNPlayObservers list dump:
256 1700786563821 GEN4_CONNECT_DIAGNOSTICS:com.microchip.mplab.mdbcore.RI4Tool.RI4ToolBase$RI4PlugNPlayObserver@390850fb
256 1700786563821 GEN4_CONNECT_DIAGNOSTICS:End PlugNPlayObservers list dump:
256 1700786563821 GEN4_CONNECT_DIAGNOSTICS:Registering for alternate PNP notifications. CommPnPCriteria.cPIDList = [2177, 2179, 217a, 2141, 9017, 901b, 9036, 9035], CommPnPCriteria.cSerialNumber = bur203612163

256 1700786563929 GEN4_TO_CONTROLLER_LOG:GEN4_INIT_INT_LOG_PIC16F1503 Pre:init
256 1700786563929 GEN4_TO_CONTROLLER_LOG:GEN4_INIT_INT_LOG_PIC16F1503 Payload
256 1700786563929 GEN4_TO_CONTROLLER_LOG:GEN4_INIT_INT_LOG_PIC16F1503 DeviceInfo: Values:
256 1700786563929 GEN4_TO_CONTROLLER_LOG:GEN4_INIT_INT_LOG_PIC16F1503 DeviceInfo: pcAddress = 00000002, Vpp = 9.00, useRowEraseIfVoltageIsLow = true, voltageBelowWhichUseRowErase = 2.70, deviceName = PIC16F1503, programmerType = PIC16ENH
256 1700786563929 GEN4_TO_CONTROLLER_LOG:GEN4_INIT_INT_LOG_PIC16F1503 DeviceInfo: MemInfo values:
256 1700786563929 GEN4_TO_CONTROLLER_LOG:GEN4_INIT_INT_LOG_PIC16F1503 DeviceInfo: mask = 3fff, exists = true, startAddr = 00000000, endAddr = 000007ff, rowSize = 0010, rowEraseSize = 0010, addrInc = 0001, widthProgram = 0002
256 1700786563929 GEN4_TO_CONTROLLER_LOG:GEN4_INIT_INT_LOG_PIC16F1503 DeviceInfo: mask = 3fff, exists = true, startAddr = 00008007, endAddr = 00008008, rowSize = 0001, rowEraseSize = 0000, addrInc = 0001, widthProgram = 0002
256 1700786563929 GEN4_TO_CONTROLLER_LOG:GEN4_INIT_INT_LOG_PIC16F1503 DeviceInfo: mask = 0000, exists = false, startAddr = 00000000, endAddr = 00000000, rowSize = 0000, rowEraseSize = 0000, addrInc = 0000, widthProgram = 0000
256 1700786563929 GEN4_TO_CONTROLLER_LOG:GEN4_INIT_INT_LOG_PIC16F1503 DeviceInfo: mask = 0000, exists = false, startAddr = 00000000, endAddr = 00000000, rowSize = 0000, rowEraseSize = 0000, addrInc = 0000, widthProgram = 0000
256 1700786563929 GEN4_TO_CONTROLLER_LOG:GEN4_INIT_INT_LOG_PIC16F1503 DeviceInfo: mask = 3fff, exists = true, startAddr = 00008000, endAddr = 00008003, rowSize = 0001, rowEraseSize = 0000, addrInc = 0001, widthProgram = 0002
256 1700786563929 GEN4_TO_CONTROLLER_LOG:GEN4_INIT_INT_LOG_PIC16F1503 DeviceInfo: mask = 3fff, exists = true, startAddr = 00008000, endAddr = 000081ff, rowSize = 0010, rowEraseSize = 0010, addrInc = 0001, widthProgram = 0002
256 1700786563929 GEN4_TO_CONTROLLER_LOG:GEN4_INIT_INT_LOG_PIC16F1503 DeviceInfo: mask = 0000, exists = false, startAddr = 00000000, endAddr = 00000000, rowSize = 0000, rowEraseSize = 0000, addrInc = 0001, widthProgram = 0001
256 1700786563929 GEN4_TO_CONTROLLER_LOG:GEN4_INIT_INT_LOG_PIC16F1503 DeviceInfo: mask = 0000, exists = false, startAddr = 00000000, endAddr = 00000000, rowSize = 0000, rowEraseSize = 0000, addrInc = 0000, widthProgram = 0000
256 1700786563929 GEN4_TO_CONTROLLER_LOG:GEN4_INIT_INT_LOG_PIC16F1503 DeviceInfo: mask = 0000, exists = false, startAddr = 00000000, endAddr = 00000000, rowSize = 0000, rowEraseSize = 0000, addrInc = 0000, widthProgram = 0000
256 1700786563929 GEN4_TO_CONTROLLER_LOG:GEN4_INIT_INT_LOG_PIC16F1503 DeviceInfo: mask = 0000, exists = false, startAddr = 00000000, endAddr = 00000000, rowSize = 0000, rowEraseSize = 0000, addrInc = 0000, widthProgram = 0000
256 1700786563929 GEN4_TO_CONTROLLER_LOG:GEN4_INIT_INT_LOG_PIC16F1503 DeviceInfo: mask = 0000, exists = false, startAddr = 00000000, endAddr = 00000000, rowSize = 0000, rowEraseSize = 0000, addrInc = 0001, widthProgram = 0001
256 1700786563929 GEN4_TO_CONTROLLER_LOG:GEN4_INIT_INT_LOG_PIC16F1503 DeviceInfo: mask = 0000, exists = false, startAddr = 00000000, endAddr = 00000000, rowSize = 0000, rowEraseSize = 0000, addrInc = 0000, widthProgram = 0000
256 1700786563929 GEN4_TO_CONTROLLER_LOG:GEN4_INIT_INT_LOG_PIC16F1503 DeviceInfo: mask = 0000, exists = false, startAddr = 00000000, endAddr = 00000000, rowSize = 0000, rowEraseSize = 0000, addrInc = 0000, widthProgram = 0000
256 1700786563929 GEN4_TO_CONTROLLER_LOG:GEN4_INIT_INT_LOG_PIC16F1503 DeviceInfo: mask = 0000, exists = false, startAddr = 00000000, endAddr = 00000000, rowSize = 0000, rowEraseSize = 0000, addrInc = 0000, widthProgram = 0000
256 1700786563929 GEN4_TO_CONTROLLER_LOG:GEN4_INIT_INT_LOG_PIC16F1503 DeviceInfo: mask = 0000, exists = false, startAddr = 00000000, endAddr = 00000000, rowSize = 0000, rowEraseSize = 0000, addrInc = 0000, widthProgram = 0000
256 1700786563929 GEN4_TO_CONTROLLER_LOG:GEN4_INIT_INT_LOG_PIC16F1503 DeviceInfo: mask = 0000, exists = false, startAddr = 00000000, endAddr = 00000000, rowSize = 0000, rowEraseSize = 0000, addrInc = 0000, widthProgram = 0000
256 1700786563929 GEN4_TO_CONTROLLER_LOG:GEN4_INIT_INT_LOG_PIC16F1503 DeviceInfo: mask = 7fffffff, exists = true, startAddr = 00008006, endAddr = 00008006, rowSize = 0001, rowEraseSize = 0000, addrInc = 0001, widthProgram = 0001
256 1700786563929 GEN4_TO_CONTROLLER_LOG:GEN4_INIT_INT_LOG_PIC16F1503 DeviceInfo: mask = 0000, exists = false, startAddr = 00000000, endAddr = 00000000, rowSize = 0000, rowEraseSize = 0000, addrInc = 0000, widthProgram = 0000
256 1700786563930 GEN4_TO_CONTROLLER_LOG:GEN4_INIT_INT_LOG_PIC16F1503 DeviceInfo: mask = 0000, exists = false, startAddr = 00000000, endAddr = 00000000, rowSize = 0000, rowEraseSize = 0000, addrInc = 0000, widthProgram = 0000
256 1700786563930 GEN4_TO_CONTROLLER_LOG:GEN4_INIT_INT_LOG_PIC16F1503 DeviceInfo: mask = 0000, exists = false, startAddr = 00000000, endAddr = 00000000, rowSize = 0000, rowEraseSize = 0000, addrInc = 0000, widthProgram = 0000
256 1700786563930 GEN4_TO_CONTROLLER_LOG:GEN4_INIT_INT_LOG_PIC16F1503 DeviceInfo: mask = 0000, exists = false, startAddr = 00000000, endAddr = 00000000, rowSize = 0000, rowEraseSize = 0000, addrInc = 0000, widthProgram = 0000
256 1700786563930 GEN4_TO_CONTROLLER_LOG:GEN4_INIT_INT_LOG_PIC16F1503 DeviceInfo: mask = 0000, exists = false, startAddr = 00000000, endAddr = 00000000, rowSize = 0000, rowEraseSize = 0000, addrInc = 0000, widthProgram = 0000
256 1700786563930 GEN4_TO_CONTROLLER_LOG:GEN4_INIT_INT_LOG_PIC16F1503 DeviceInfo: mask = 0000, exists = false, startAddr = 00000000, endAddr = 00000000, rowSize = 0000, rowEraseSize = 0000, addrInc = 0000, widthProgram = 0000
256 1700786563930 GEN4_TO_CONTROLLER_LOG:GEN4_INIT_INT_LOG_PIC16F1503 DeviceInfo: CfgRequiredBitsMask Values:
256 1700786563930 GEN4_TO_CONTROLLER_LOG:GEN4_INIT_INT_LOG_PIC16F1503 Address = 00008007, Mask = 00000efb
256 1700786563930 GEN4_TO_CONTROLLER_LOG:GEN4_INIT_INT_LOG_PIC16F1503 Address = 00008008, Mask = 00002e03
256 1700786563930 GEN4_TO_CONTROLLER_LOG:GEN4_INIT_INT_LOG_PIC16F1503 BasicInfo: Values:
256 1700786563930 GEN4_TO_CONTROLLER_LOG:GEN4_INIT_INT_LOG_PIC16F1503 BasicInfo: InputStream = com.microchip.mplab.libs.toolpacksupport.EquatableFileInputStream@4e67ed6a, ToolFlavor = PICKit4
256 1700786563930 GEN4_TO_CONTROLLER_LOG:GEN4_INIT_INT_LOG_PIC16F1503 Payload End
256 1700786563930 GEN4_TO_CONTROLLER_LOG:GEN4_INIT_INT_LOG_PIC16F1503 Post:init
256 1700786563930 GEN4_TO_CONTROLLER_LOG:GEN4_INIT_INT_LOG_PIC16F1503 Return Value
256 1700786563930 GEN4_TO_CONTROLLER_LOG:GEN4_INIT_INT_LOG_PIC16F1503 none
256 1700786563930 GEN4_TO_CONTROLLER_LOG:GEN4_INIT_INT_LOG_PIC16F1503 Return End

256 1700786563930 GEN4_TO_CONTROLLER_LOG:GEN4_INIT_INT_LOG_PIC16F1503 Pre:GetInterfaceProvider
256 1700786563930 GEN4_TO_CONTROLLER_LOG:GEN4_INIT_INT_LOG_PIC16F1503 Payload
256 1700786563930 GEN4_TO_CONTROLLER_LOG:GEN4_INIT_INT_LOG_PIC16F1503 RI4DebugInterface
256 1700786563930 GEN4_TO_CONTROLLER_LOG:GEN4_INIT_INT_LOG_PIC16F1503 Payload End
256 1700786563930 GEN4_TO_CONTROLLER_LOG:GEN4_INIT_INT_LOG_PIC16F1503 Post:GetInterfaceProvider
256 1700786563930 GEN4_TO_CONTROLLER_LOG:GEN4_INIT_INT_LOG_PIC16F1503 Return Value
256 1700786563930 GEN4_TO_CONTROLLER_LOG:GEN4_INIT_INT_LOG_PIC16F1503 com.microchip.mplab.libs.RI4ToolsController.implementations.RI4DebugInterfaceImpl@2b9ee8cc
256 1700786563930 GEN4_TO_CONTROLLER_LOG:GEN4_INIT_INT_LOG_PIC16F1503 Return End

256 1700786563934 GEN4_TO_CONTROLLER_LOG:GEN4_INIT_INT_LOG_PIC16F1503 Pre:GetInterfaceProvider
256 1700786563934 GEN4_TO_CONTROLLER_LOG:GEN4_INIT_INT_LOG_PIC16F1503 Payload
256 1700786563934 GEN4_TO_CONTROLLER_LOG:GEN4_INIT_INT_LOG_PIC16F1503 RI4ProgramInterface
256 1700786563934 GEN4_TO_CONTROLLER_LOG:GEN4_INIT_INT_LOG_PIC16F1503 Payload End
256 1700786563934 GEN4_TO_CONTROLLER_LOG:GEN4_INIT_INT_LOG_PIC16F1503 Post:GetInterfaceProvider
256 1700786563934 GEN4_TO_CONTROLLER_LOG:GEN4_INIT_INT_LOG_PIC16F1503 Return Value
256 1700786563934 GEN4_TO_CONTROLLER_LOG:GEN4_INIT_INT_LOG_PIC16F1503 com.microchip.mplab.libs.RI4ToolsController.implementations.RI4ProgramInterfaceImpl@46b212e7
256 1700786563934 GEN4_TO_CONTROLLER_LOG:GEN4_INIT_INT_LOG_PIC16F1503 Return End

256 1700786563935 GEN4_TO_CONTROLLER_LOG:GEN4_INIT_INT_LOG_PIC16F1503 Pre:GetInterfaceProvider
256 1700786563935 GEN4_TO_CONTROLLER_LOG:GEN4_INIT_INT_LOG_PIC16F1503 Payload
256 1700786563935 GEN4_TO_CONTROLLER_LOG:GEN4_INIT_INT_LOG_PIC16F1503 RI4ConnectInterface
256 1700786563935 GEN4_TO_CONTROLLER_LOG:GEN4_INIT_INT_LOG_PIC16F1503 Payload End
256 1700786563935 GEN4_TO_CONTROLLER_LOG:GEN4_INIT_INT_LOG_PIC16F1503 Post:GetInterfaceProvider
256 1700786563935 GEN4_TO_CONTROLLER_LOG:GEN4_INIT_INT_LOG_PIC16F1503 Return Value
256 1700786563935 GEN4_TO_CONTROLLER_LOG:GEN4_INIT_INT_LOG_PIC16F1503 com.microchip.mplab.libs.PK4ToolsController.PK4ConnectInterfaceImpl@3d460d42
256 1700786563935 GEN4_TO_CONTROLLER_LOG:GEN4_INIT_INT_LOG_PIC16F1503 Return End
256 1700786563935 GEN4_CONNECT_DIAGNOSTICS:acceptablePIDs = [9012, 9017, 901b, 9036, 9035]
256 1700786563935 GEN4_CONNECT_DIAGNOSTICS:otherPIDs = [2177, 2179, 217a, 2141]
256 1700786563935 GEN4_CONNECT_DIAGNOSTICS:Setting selected tool type to pk4
256 1700786563935 GEN4_CONNECT_DIAGNOSTICS:otherPIDs = [2177, 2179, 217a, 2141]
256 1700786563935 GEN4_CONNECT_DIAGNOSTICS:acceptablePIDs = [9012, 9017, 901b, 9036, 9035]

256 1700786563935 GEN4_TO_CONTROLLER_LOG:GEN4_INIT_INT_LOG_PIC16F1503 Pre:GetInterfaceProvider
256 1700786563935 GEN4_TO_CONTROLLER_LOG:GEN4_INIT_INT_LOG_PIC16F1503 Payload
256 1700786563935 GEN4_TO_CONTROLLER_LOG:GEN4_INIT_INT_LOG_PIC16F1503 RI4ControllerDiagnosticsInterface
256 1700786563935 GEN4_TO_CONTROLLER_LOG:GEN4_INIT_INT_LOG_PIC16F1503 Payload End
256 1700786563935 GEN4_TO_CONTROLLER_LOG:GEN4_INIT_INT_LOG_PIC16F1503 Post:GetInterfaceProvider
256 1700786563935 GEN4_TO_CONTROLLER_LOG:GEN4_INIT_INT_LOG_PIC16F1503 Return Value
256 1700786563935 GEN4_TO_CONTROLLER_LOG:GEN4_INIT_INT_LOG_PIC16F1503 com.microchip.mplab.libs.RI4ToolsController.implementations.RI4ControllerDiagnosticsInterfaceImpl@48dca29b
256 1700786563935 GEN4_TO_CONTROLLER_LOG:GEN4_INIT_INT_LOG_PIC16F1503 Return End

256 1700786563935 GEN4_TO_CONTROLLER_LOG:GEN4_INIT_INT_LOG_PIC16F1503 Pre:GetInterfaceProvider
256 1700786563935 GEN4_TO_CONTROLLER_LOG:GEN4_INIT_INT_LOG_PIC16F1503 Payload
256 1700786563935 GEN4_TO_CONTROLLER_LOG:GEN4_INIT_INT_LOG_PIC16F1503 ProgrammerToGo
256 1700786563935 GEN4_TO_CONTROLLER_LOG:GEN4_INIT_INT_LOG_PIC16F1503 Payload End
256 1700786563935 GEN4_TO_CONTROLLER_LOG:GEN4_INIT_INT_LOG_PIC16F1503 Post:GetInterfaceProvider
256 1700786563935 GEN4_TO_CONTROLLER_LOG:GEN4_INIT_INT_LOG_PIC16F1503 Return Value
256 1700786563935 GEN4_TO_CONTROLLER_LOG:GEN4_INIT_INT_LOG_PIC16F1503 com.microchip.mplab.libs.RI4ToolsController.implementations.ProgrammerToGoImpl@1458fbc4
256 1700786563935 GEN4_TO_CONTROLLER_LOG:GEN4_INIT_INT_LOG_PIC16F1503 Return End

256 1700786563935 GEN4_TO_CONTROLLER_LOG:GEN4_INIT_INT_LOG_PIC16F1503 Pre:GetInterfaceProvider
256 1700786563935 GEN4_TO_CONTROLLER_LOG:GEN4_INIT_INT_LOG_PIC16F1503 Payload
256 1700786563935 GEN4_TO_CONTROLLER_LOG:GEN4_INIT_INT_LOG_PIC16F1503 Status
256 1700786563935 GEN4_TO_CONTROLLER_LOG:GEN4_INIT_INT_LOG_PIC16F1503 Payload End
256 1700786563935 GEN4_TO_CONTROLLER_LOG:GEN4_INIT_INT_LOG_PIC16F1503 Post:GetInterfaceProvider
256 1700786563935 GEN4_TO_CONTROLLER_LOG:GEN4_INIT_INT_LOG_PIC16F1503 Return Value
256 1700786563935 GEN4_TO_CONTROLLER_LOG:GEN4_INIT_INT_LOG_PIC16F1503 null
256 1700786563935 GEN4_TO_CONTROLLER_LOG:GEN4_INIT_INT_LOG_PIC16F1503 Return End

256 1700786563941 GEN4_TO_CONTROLLER_LOG:GEN4_PROGRAM_INT_LOG_PIC16F1503 Pre:SetDebugExec
256 1700786563941 GEN4_TO_CONTROLLER_LOG:GEN4_PROGRAM_INT_LOG_PIC16F1503 Payload
256 1700786563941 GEN4_TO_CONTROLLER_LOG:GEN4_PROGRAM_INT_LOG_PIC16F1503 Test
256 1700786563941 GEN4_TO_CONTROLLER_LOG:GEN4_PROGRAM_INT_LOG_PIC16F1503 8020
256 1700786563941 GEN4_TO_CONTROLLER_LOG:GEN4_PROGRAM_INT_LOG_PIC16F1503 Length = 874
256 1700786563941 GEN4_TO_CONTROLLER_LOG:GEN4_PROGRAM_INT_LOG_PIC16F1503 Payload End
256 1700786563941 GEN4_TO_CONTROLLER_LOG:GEN4_PROGRAM_INT_LOG_PIC16F1503 Post:SetDebugExec
256 1700786563941 GEN4_TO_CONTROLLER_LOG:GEN4_PROGRAM_INT_LOG_PIC16F1503 Return Value
256 1700786563941 GEN4_TO_CONTROLLER_LOG:GEN4_PROGRAM_INT_LOG_PIC16F1503 true
256 1700786563941 GEN4_TO_CONTROLLER_LOG:GEN4_PROGRAM_INT_LOG_PIC16F1503 Return End
256 1700786563942 GEN4_CONNECT_DIAGNOSTICS:ENTERING: com.microchip.mplab.mdbcore.RI4Tool.ConnectionHandler.CheckForFWUpdates()
256 1700786563942 GEN4_CONNECT_DIAGNOSTICS:Created FirmwareUpdateHandler com.microchip.mplab.mdbcore.pk4hybrid.pk4hybridFirmwareUpdateHandler@62ef6488
256 1700786563942 GEN4_CONNECT_DIAGNOSTICS:ENTERING: com.microchip.mplab.mdbcore.RI4Tool.FirmwareUpdateHandler.UpdateFirmware(FirmwareInfo, UpdateMessage)
256 1700786563942 GEN4_CONNECT_DIAGNOSTICS:areWeInBoot returned false
256 1700786563942 GEN4_CONNECT_DIAGNOSTICS:inBoot = false
256 1700786563942 GEN4_CONNECT_DIAGNOSTICS:uMode = checkingVersions
256 1700786563942 GEN4_CONNECT_DIAGNOSTICS:selectedTool = pk4
256 1700786563942 GEN4_CONNECT_DIAGNOSTICS:current toolType = pk4
256 1700786563942 GEN4_CONNECT_DIAGNOSTICS:current tool mode = pk4
256 1700786563942 GEN4_CONNECT_DIAGNOSTICS:ENTERING: com.microchip.mplab.mdbcore.RI4Tool.FirmwareUpdateHandler.GetUpdateInfo()
256 1700786563942 GEN4_CONNECT_DIAGNOSTICS:Parsing file  for firmware updates
256 1700786563942 GEN4_CONNECT_DIAGNOSTICS:ENTERING: com.microchip.mplab.mdbcore.RI4Tool.FirmwareUpdateHandler.ParseSelectedVersionsFromJamFile()
256 1700786563942 GEN4_CONNECT_DIAGNOSTICS:Jame file line = boot.hex,010000
256 1700786563942 GEN4_CONNECT_DIAGNOSTICS:Jame file line = scripts.xml,000585
256 1700786563942 GEN4_CONNECT_DIAGNOSTICS:Jame file line = app1 020085, 0040C000
256 1700786563942 GEN4_CONNECT_DIAGNOSTICS:Jame file line = app2 1.14.268, 00500000
256 1700786563942 GEN4_CONNECT_DIAGNOSTICS:Jame file line = app3 000000, FFFFFFFF
256 1700786563942 GEN4_CONNECT_DIAGNOSTICS:Jame file line = app4 000000, FFFFFFFF
256 1700786563942 GEN4_CONNECT_DIAGNOSTICS:Jame file line = app5 000000, FFFFFFFF
256 1700786563942 GEN4_CONNECT_DIAGNOSTICS:Jame file line = app6 000000, FFFFFFFF
256 1700786563942 GEN4_CONNECT_DIAGNOSTICS:Jame file line = app7 000000, FFFFFFFF
256 1700786563942 GEN4_CONNECT_DIAGNOSTICS:Jame file line = app8 000000, FFFFFFFF
256 1700786563942 GEN4_CONNECT_DIAGNOSTICS:EXITING: com.microchip.mplab.mdbcore.RI4Tool.FirmwareUpdateHandler.ri4ParseSelectedVersionsFromJamFile()
256 1700786563942 GEN4_CONNECT_DIAGNOSTICS:EXITING: com.microchip.mplab.mdbcore.RI4Tool.FirmwareUpdateHandler.GetUpdateInfo()
256 1700786563942 GEN4_CONNECT_DIAGNOSTICS:current toolType = pk4

256 1700786563942 GEN4_TO_CONTROLLER_LOG:GEN4_CONNECT_INT_LOG_PIC16F1503 Pre:EstablishCommunincations
256 1700786563942 GEN4_TO_CONTROLLER_LOG:GEN4_CONNECT_INT_LOG_PIC16F1503 Payload
256 1700786563942 GEN4_TO_CONTROLLER_LOG:GEN4_CONNECT_INT_LOG_PIC16F1503 com.microchip.mplab.mdbcore.PK4Tool.PK4Com@5db61ef6
256 1700786563942 GEN4_TO_CONTROLLER_LOG:GEN4_CONNECT_INT_LOG_PIC16F1503 Payload End
256 1700786563943 GEN4_TO_CONTROLLER_LOG:GEN4_CONNECT_INT_LOG_PIC16F1503 Post:EstablishCommunincations
256 1700786563943 GEN4_TO_CONTROLLER_LOG:GEN4_CONNECT_INT_LOG_PIC16F1503 Return Value
256 1700786563943 GEN4_TO_CONTROLLER_LOG:GEN4_CONNECT_INT_LOG_PIC16F1503 true
256 1700786563943 GEN4_TO_CONTROLLER_LOG:GEN4_CONNECT_INT_LOG_PIC16F1503 Return End

256 1700786563943 GEN4_TO_CONTROLLER_LOG:GEN4_CONNECT_INT_LOG_PIC16F1503 Pre:GetFirmwareInfo
256 1700786563943 GEN4_TO_CONTROLLER_LOG:GEN4_CONNECT_INT_LOG_PIC16F1503 Payload
256 1700786563943 GEN4_TO_CONTROLLER_LOG:GEN4_CONNECT_INT_LOG_PIC16F1503 null
256 1700786563943 GEN4_TO_CONTROLLER_LOG:GEN4_CONNECT_INT_LOG_PIC16F1503 Payload End
256 1700786563944 XXXX 1700786563943, Thread 256: com.Send returned false 
256 1700786563944 XXXX 1700786563944, Thread 256: execCommand: exception after writeSideChanel null
```

Any suggestions to fix the issue?

Comment: This https://forum.microchip.com/s/topic/a5C3l000000MQ8WEAW/t330528 may be relevant - you have to dig down, but most issues seem to be related to poor USB cables or lack of "common ground" between the target and the PC, especially when using a laptop with un grounded PSU.